# What does $\varphi (n)$ denote in the context 'the class of $q$ modulo $n$ has order $\varphi (n)$'?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, cyclotomic-polynomials

I am currently trying to understand the following condition (found [here](http://www.usthb.dz/fmath/IMG/pdf/cours_du_professeur_michel_waldschmidt_finite_fields_2014_1_.pdf#page=28) in Corollary 48) which tells us when the $n^\text{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n (x)$ (over a finite field) is irreducible:

> The $n^\text{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n (x)$ is irreducible in $F_q [x]$ iff the class of $q$ modulo $n$ has order $\varphi (n)$

I am hoping that someone might be able to help me understand what this means by explaining what $\varphi (n)$ denotes?

Comment: It's almost certainly Euler's totient function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This refers to the Euler totient: the number of integers less than $n$ which are coprime to $n$. Your hypothesis is that $q$ has order $\phi(n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$: equivalently, that $q$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.